# Can I sign the uninstaller for my program?

Tags: installshield, signing, uninstallation

For reference, I am using InstallShield 2015 and the project is a Basic MSI.

I know the uninstaller is created automatically, what I do not like about it is how I'm always shown the "Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer?" warning.

Is there a way to sign the uninstaller the same way I do with the program itself so that users don't need to see this warning?

Comment: What OS version are you seeing this on?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - I believe it's Windows 7.

Comment: What project type are you using?  InstallScript, Basic MSI, InstallScript MSI?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - Basic MSI

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Basic MSI and Windows 7, I don't know why you'd get this message.

In Windows NT/2K/XP/Vista,  MSI stripped the storage out of an MSI and stored it in c:\windows\installer.  This was for space considerations and it would resolve the full MSI if content was needed.

In Vista they added UAC and the complaint was uninstall would say unknown publisher because stripping the storage invalidated the cert.

In Windows 7 and beyond they cache the full MSI.  So this shouldn't be an issue.  A further examination of your environment and uninstall log file would be required to give a better answer.